# Use HashSet with a user defined class in an Xtext validator

Tags: dsl, xtext, xtend

I'm writing a small DSL that stores a list of coordinates:

```
Model:
    locations+=Coordinates*
;
Coordinates:
    '(' x=INT ',' y=INT ')'
;
```

I'm working now on the validator, and one of the things I want to make sure is that the list does not contain the same location (set of coordinates) twice.  For this, I've written the following validator check:

```
@Check
def checkLocation(Model model) {
    val locationSet = newHashSet
    for (location : model.locations) {
        if (!locationSet.add(location)) {
            error('Locations must be unique.', location, LOCATION)
        }
    }
}
```

So that the locations get added to a `HashSet` and an error occurs if the same locations gets added twice.  However, this doesn't work (the error never gets triggered).  I'm guessing because the class `Coordinates` does not define the `hashCode` and `equals` methods that are required for the `HashSet` to work.

Any ideas on how could I make the `HashSet` work? Is it possible to define the implementation of the `hashCode` and `equals` methods of the generated class?

Comment: did you consider to add pairs of ints to the set instead of the objects

Comment: I ended up with a similar solution, adding them as a string concatenating both coordinates. But I am still curious, is it possible to make it work with a user defined class? Is there a way of defining `hashCode` and `equals` as you would do in regular Java code?

Comment: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/159986/ says you shall not customize equals and hashcode